# gradlew assembleRelease and gradlew assembleReleaseStaging producing APK without changes

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am trying to bundle my APK. When I use `gradlew assembleRelease` or `assembleReleaseStaging` there are no changes in my app. When I use `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res` before assembling it creates a lot of new files, if i delete all of them except `index.android.bundle` and run `gradlew assembleRelease` or `gradlew assembleReleaseStaging` everything works just fine. My question is - is there any way to assemble release **without** manual bundling? I have tried gradlew clean and other ways found on stackoverflow. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook `react.gradle` to your module's `build.gradle`.
Go to `app/build.gradle` and add the following:

```
// Configures the bundleJS commands for React-Native
project.ext.react = [

    // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
    bundleInDebug: false,
    // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
    bundleInRelease: true, 

    // the root of your RN project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
    root: "path_to_rn_project_directory"
]
apply from: "<path to RN project>/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

After this, `assembleRelease` will start bundling as well.

Comment: Done as you told, still have no updates in my apk ( Maybe there is something else i should do? My current project.ext.react looks like this :  
project.ext.react = [  
    entryFile: "index.js",  
    bundleInDebug: false,  
    bundleInRelease: true,   
    root: "../../"  
]  
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"  
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"